# How join other sheet to main sheet like DB relation?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet name 'test'

```
code | count
HHHD |   
YTSS |
YDUS |
```

and i have a second sheet name 'abc'

```
code | count | name
HHHD |   1   | sts
YTSS |   2   | other_name
YDUS |   6   | other_name_2
```

How create array formula or which function use to make in test B2 cell when code from test  will exist in abc.cell then get data abc.count and insert to test.count

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic `VLOOKUP` case:

But, I'll use `LOOKUP` here

Test B2=

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(A2:A7,'abc'!A2:B7))
```

Comment: `LOOKUP` is smaller 

Answer (score 1):

The QUERY function offers a short, readable way to analyze data. This function uses the principles of Structured Query Language (SQL) to do searches.

Parts of a QUERY formula
A QUERY formula is formatted as `=QUERY(data, query, [headers]).`

> Full Documentation : [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)